# Angular 4 Material components ordering

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Super beginner in front technologies I am working on an Angular 4 application using some material components. I am trying to display all my material components on one line. But I can't find a material directive like `mat-group-element`, here is my code so far :

My `main-component.css` :

```
 .sqltool-input {
    display:inline-block
  }

  .sqltool-select {
    display:inline-block
  }

  .sqltool-toggle {
    display:inline-block
  }
```

My `main-component.html` :

```
<form class="sqltool-form">
   <!-- COMPONENT 1 -->  
   <mat-form-field class="sqltool-matform">
     <input class="sqltool-input" matInput placeholder="Enter SQL request">

    <!-- COMPONENT 2 --> 
    <mat-select class="sqltool-select" placeholder="Base" [(ngModel)]="dataSource">
        <mat-option value="Base1">Base 1</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Base2">Base 2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>

    <!-- COMPONENT 3 --> 
    <mat-slide-toggle class="sqltool-toggle" [checked]="checked" color="primary">
        File generation
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: mat-form-field should be around a single element, not around all of them.

Comment: @Carsten It seems like it was the issue when I put a <mat-form-field> on both first components it worked, but on all three components it didn't and on only the first one it didn't.. I don't understand why it worked for the first case

Comment: mat-slide-toggle does not require a mat-form-field around it

Comment: ok got it, do you want to edit an answer so i can validate it, or I edit mine resulting of your comment ?  @Carsten
It worked well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview); Only three material components are designed to work inside a mat-form-field:

- Input matInput & textarea matInput
- mat-select
- mat-chip-list